# Create html div's in a loop in RMarkdown

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I would like to be able to create several HTML div's in a loop in `rmarkdown`. However, it does not seem to work quite well. What I am trying to create is a `bsplus::bs_modal()` and then attach these modal to a button.

Minimal `.Rmd` reprex with desired outcome:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---
  
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(magrittr)
```
  
```{r}
bsplus::bs_modal(id = paste0("button_", 1), title = paste0("modal ", 1), body = NULL)
bsplus::bs_modal(id = paste0("button_", 2), title = paste0("modal ", 2), body = NULL)
```
  
```{r}
bsplus::bs_button("Modal 1") %>% 
  bsplus::bs_attach_modal("button_1")
```
  
```{r}
bsplus::bs_button("Modal 2") %>% 
  bsplus::bs_attach_modal("button_2")
```
````

Minimal `.Rmd` reprex with the approach I am using but it is not working:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(magrittr)
```

```{r results='asis'}
lapply(1:2, function(i) {
  bsplus::bs_modal(id = paste0("button_", i), title = paste0("modal ", i), body = NULL)
})
```

```{r results='asis'}
lapply(1:2, function(i) {
  bsplus::bs_button(paste0("Modal ", i)) %>% 
    bsplus::bs_attach_modal(paste0("button_", i))
})
```
````

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `htmltools::tagList()`

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(magrittr)
```

```{r results='asis'}
htmltools::tagList(lapply(1:2, function(i) {
  bsplus::bs_modal(id = paste0("button_", i), title = paste0("modal ", i), body = NULL)
}))
```

```{r results='asis'}
htmltools::tagList(lapply(1:2, function(i) {
  bsplus::bs_button(paste0("Modal ", i)) %>% 
    bsplus::bs_attach_modal(paste0("button_", i))
}))
```
````